# const char * to vector<unsigned char> Initalisation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, char, initialization

I understand that using vector is a good way to store binary data when using C++ and the STL. However for my unit tests I'd like to initalise the vector using a const char* C string variable.

I'm attempting to use a variant of the code found here - [Converting (void*) to std::vector<unsigned char>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725040/converting-void-to-stdvectorunsigned-char) - to do this:

```
const char* testdata = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)testdata;
typedef vector<unsigned char> bufferType;

bufferType::size_type size = strlen((const char*)buffer);
bufferType vec(buffer, size);
```

However the VC++ compiler is not happy with the line initialising the vector, stating:

```
error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(unsigned int,const _Ty &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'unsigned int'
```

I appreciate the extreme n00bity of this question and am fully prepared for much criticism on the code above :)

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: You are much better off using:    

    `std::vector<std::string> vec;`
    `vec.push_back("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");`

Comment: The code under test will eventually be used to handle binary data, hence the preference for vector<unsigned char>. For the tests, I'd like to initialise it using const char* data.

Comment: You can get the underlying char data simply by using `std::string::c_str()`, and you save a lot of potential problems of using raw pointers.Not a bad deal IMO.

Comment: This was my original approach, but was worried that using c_str() might throw an additional \0 byte at the end of the array. Good for strings, not good for binary data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should be

```
bufferType vec(buffer, buffer + size);
```

not

```
bufferType vec(buffer, size);
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::transform` is useful for just this sort of problem.  You can use it to "transform" one piece of data at a time.  See documentation here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/

The following code works in VS2010.  (I created a `std::string` from your `const char*` array, but you could probably avoid that if you really wanted to.)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main(int, char*[])
{
  // Initial test data
  const char* testdata = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

  // Transform from 'const char*' to 'vector<unsigned char>'
  std::string input(testdata);
  std::vector<unsigned char> output(input.length());
  std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(),
    [](char c)
    {
      return static_cast<unsigned char>(c);
    });

  // Use the transformed data in 'output'...


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me:

```
// Fetch data into vector
std::vector<char> buffer = <myMethod>.getdata();

// Get a char pointer to the data in the vector
char* buf = buffer.data();

// cast from char pointer to unsigned char pointer
unsigned char* membuf = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buf);            

// now convert to vector<unsigned char> buffer
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(membuf, membuf + buffer.size()); 

// display vector<unsigned char>   
CUtils::<myMethodToShowDataBlock>(vec);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you intended to do seems to be something like:

```
buffertype vec(testdata, next(testdata, strlen(testdata)));
```

There is no need for the intermediate `buffer` variable. The conversion from `char` to `unsigned char` will happen implicitly.

Note that this does not grab the terminating `'\0'` character from `testdata`. So if you wanted to be able to do something like: `cout << vec.data()` you wouldn't be able to. If you want that you could do: `buffertype vec(testdata, next(testdata, strlen(testdata) + 1))` or you may just want to consider doing:

```
basic_string<unsigned char> vec(testdata, next(testdata, strlen(testdata)));
```

Which will preserve a hidden `'\0'`. Because this is not a `string` you won't be able to do, `cout << vec` but `cout << vec.data()` will work. I've created a [<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/KWRxXg) of each of these.

Comment: I do not see how this could work if you are using large binary buffers as testdata

Comment: @serup The OP says: "I'd like to initalise the `vector` using a `const char*` C string variable." I'm demonstrating how to do that. Note that we can only use a `char*` to represent a string because of the terminating character: `'\0'` A terminating character is inappropriate for binary data though, so size would have to be maintained separately from the `char*`. In this situation you'd need to replace the `strlen(testdata)` in my answer with the given size.